# How to set the default outbound interface in Debian when using multihomed interfaces on EC2

Tags: debian, routing, dhcp, amazon-ec2, network-interface

In Debian 10 with an Amazon EC2 AMI (as of March 31, 2021), the `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# Cloud images dynamically generate config fragments for newly
# attached interfaces. See /etc/udev/rules.d/75-cloud-ifupdown.rules
# and /etc/network/cloud-ifupdown-helper. Dynamically generated
# configuration fragments are stored in /run:
source-directory /run/network/interfaces.d
```

The contents of `/run/network/interfaces.d/eth0` are:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet6 manual
  try_dhcp 1
```

This brings up the `eth0` interface and configures its IPv4 address via Amazon's DHCP server.  Let's say Amazon's DHCP server always assigns my server the IP address `192.168.1.55`.

So far so good.

In order to multihome my host, I have created the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0_1` as follows:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.2/24
```

This causes the system to create an `eth0:1` interface with IP address of `192.168.1.2` on the same subnet the DHCP server gives us.

The problem is that because the `/etc/network/interfaces` file sources entries in `/etc/network/interfaces.d` *before* entries in `/run/network/interfaces.d` the `eth0:1` interface is created *before* `eth0` which cause its IP address (`192.168.1.2`) to be assigned as the default outbound route IP.

So when we display the routing table we get somethin like:

`ip route show`:

```
default via 192.16.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
```

The problem with this is that Amazon's gateway at `192.168.1.1` drops any traffic from my host that doesn't originate from `192.168.1.55`.

Obviously, it's easy enough to reorder the include directives in `/etc/network/interfaces` to source the `eth0` file first, but what I'm wondering is if it's possible in the `eth0_1` file or via some other mechanism (dhclient.conf?) to force the default ip route link source to be "whatever IP address eth0 has" (i.e. `192.168.1.55`).

I've read the man pages but I'm a bit leery of experimenting lest I break the network config and make my EC2 host inaccessible.